# Getting GNU Make to parse shell config files in OSX?

Tags: macos, makefile, gnu-make

I've got a makefile for installing my personal repo of config files, part of which is compiling my emacs scripts:

```
compile:
    emacs -batch --eval "(progn (load \"~/.emacs\") (byte-recompile-directory \"~/.emacs.d\" 0))"
```

The problem is, on OSX, I have an alias called "emacs" that points to the Emacs.app binary for use in a terminal, this is defined in my ~/.bash_profile.

Now, no matter what I do, I can't seem to get the shell that Make is calling to read a startup file to load that alias, so that compilation step always fails.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Start your own shell... `bash -c ‘emacs ....’`

Comment: No dice unfortunately...

Comment: Maybe `bash —login -c ...`? That’s double dash login.

Comment: This is exactly the opposite of what the question asks.  By specifying `--login` you're forcing bash to read `.bash_profile` and to set the alias: he wants to _not_ set the alias.  As for the first suggestion, that's what make already does so it won't make any difference.

Comment: @MadScientist You are right, thank you for keeping me on the straight and narrow.

Comment: No never mind, I'm wrong.  I completely misunderstood the question: I thought the problem was that the alias was being used but the problem is that the alias is NOT being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.bash_profile` is only read by interactive login shells.  Exported environment variables set in it are inherited through the process environment, which means that these settings are generally available to all programs the user starts (if bash is indeed the login shell, of course).

No such inheritance happens for aliases, though.  Bash supports exported functions, but that's an obscure feature which can easily break other programs (for example, those which assume that environment variable values do not contain newlines).  If you go that route, you may have to use `.bashrc` instead, to make sure that these functions are exported by interactive bash shells which are not login shells.

I expected the easiest solution is to put a directory like `$HOME/bin` on the `PATH` (in `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc`, whatever works best) and put an `emacs` wrapper script into that directory which invokes the actual binary using `exec /path/to/Emacs.app "$@"` (or maybe just a symbolic link would do).

Comment: I suspect this is the way to go too.

Comment: Until you figure out how aliases are leaking into your sub-shells, you'll never be able to rely on builds working properly (or other tools that invoke subshells).  That absolutely should not happen: something is not right about your shell configuration or environment.

Answer (score 1):

That is very strange.  Aliases are not exported to sub-shells, and the `.bash_profile` script is only run by interactive shells: make doesn't invoke an interactive shell (by default).  So, it's hard to understand how the shell make invokes would see that alias based on the information you've provided.

Maybe you set the `BASH_ENV` shell variable somewhere?  You should never do that, unless you really know what you're doing.

Maybe you reset make's `.SHELLFLAGS` variable to force a login shell?  You shouldn't to that either.

Anyway, you can try using `command` which avoids aliases etc.  Unfortunately make doesn't know this is a shell-built in, so you have to convince it to run a shell.  This will be fixed in the next release of GNU make but Apple will never ship that.

```
compile:
        command emacs -batch --eval "(progn (load \"~/.emacs\") (byte-recompile-directory \"~/.emacs.d\" 0))" && true
```

Comment: Yeah, not setting BASH_ENV or mucking with .SHELLFLAGS.  It's being very stubborn.

Comment: If you run "env | grep emacs" what do you see?  If you run "env | grep BASH" what do you see?

Comment: Sorry, to elaborate, it's _not_ seeing the alias I setup, which is the problem, it's defaulting back to the emacs 22 that comes with OSX by default, which is causing Bad Things to happen...

Comment: Hrm.  OK I see, I totally misunderstood your question.